# Как получить ссылку на фото внутри поста во вконтакте и id самого поста

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, selenium

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня получилось достать текст поста, а ссылку на фото в посте нет.
Я хотел найти ссылку через CssSelector , но я не могу понять по какому id получить (a)

```
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/badyi/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://vk.com//feed");
        IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("post_link"));
        element.Click();
        string txt =driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("wall_post_text")).Text;
        var reference = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#wl_post_body a"));

       Console.WriteLine($"\n---------------------\n{txt}\n---------------------\n");
```

вылетает исключение  "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#wl_post_body a"} (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.75)"

Comment: Во первых мы не видим ваших наработок, что вы сами пробовали? Во вторых, почему селениум, почему CssSelector, почему не API?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ По заданию сказанно использовать именно Selenium так как в дальнейшем потребуется парсить сайты, которые имеют иной API или не имеют вообще. Добавил фрагмент кода + фрагмент html-кода новостной ленты в вк. А как еще тут можно получить ссылку на фото в посте? я не понял как это можно сделать в этом случае с className, name, id , TagName.